# laravel set locale globaly for carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

When I want to print a date with carbon like:

```
return Carbon::createFromDate(1992, 4, 28)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

It shows in english.

when I setlocale like:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Nl');
return Carbon::createFromDate(1992, 4, 28)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

the date is printed in the wanted way (netherlands).

I dont want to set the locale everytime I want to print the date so I tried setting it in the config/app.php file with:

```
'locale' => 'Nl',
```

but when I remove the

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Nl');
```

part from my controller where I run the carbon code it is in English again.
I could use middleware to run setlocale everytime but is there a better way to set the locale globaly?

Comment: What are your trying to achieve exactly? can you elaborate

Comment: check this package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-date

Comment: @AngadDubey set the locale only once